# Loop detection in Extreme switch

Tags: wireless, loop

I am facing problem since a month in my wireless network. I have extreme switch in my office and with switchport 22 i have given to backhaul with wireless vlan to it, the problem is that my switchport 22 automatically frequently goes down and i have to enable it all over again. So what could be the issue...

the following log msg is found when i check out the log

Warn:ELRP.Report.Message> [CLI:vlan_2:1] LOOP DETECTED :
switchport 22 down

Comment: <Warn:ELRP.Report.Message> [CLI:vlan_2:1] LOOP DETECTED : 2903709 transmitted, 21 received, ingress slot:port (16) egress slot:port (16)                     this is the complete warning that i saw in log

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question does not keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

From the scarce information you're giving, a bridge loop seems to be created across that port. The most likely case would be that one of the wireless client has got a simultaneous, wired connection and bridges in between.

Diagnostics:

- Check the WAP log for which client associates at the time the loop is detected.
- Check your network monitoring for the kind of traffic that's looping and the participating ports.

Solutions:

- Consider L2 separation (different VLANs) between wired and wireless networks.
- Consider organizational or technical policies to control network bridging by users and their use of wired and wireless connections.

Also, you might want to review your STP setup.

[edit] Your comment indicates a loop on port 16. Since both ingress and egress are on port 16, there is a loop remote to the switch. Check out which device(s) are located on that port.

Your connectivity(?) problem on port 22 may be due to the loop messing with the switch's source address table.

Comment: This is the full log msg                                                                       <Warn:ELRP.Report.Message> [CLI:vlan_2:1] LOOP DETECTED : 2898401 transmitted, 20 received, ingress slot:port (16) egress slot:port (16)